# NextJS middleware does not seem to be triggered

Tags: next.js

I have the `middleware.js` file within `/myproject/pages/middleware.js`:

```js
export function middleware(request) {
  console.log(1)
  return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/', request.url))
}

// See "Matching Paths" below to learn more
export const config = {
  matcher: ['/test'],
}
```

Now what I expect is when i go to the page `/test` then it should redirect me to `/`. However nothing happens and I see my standard 404 page.

Any ideas why?

NextJs version: 12.2.2

Comment: Looks like some code is missing. Where are you using `config`?

Answer (score 119, accepted):

Latest versions of [NextJS](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing/middleware#convention) requires the user to have a single middleware file on the same level as the pages folder.

Instead of `{root}/pages/middleware.js`, try `{root}/middleware.js`
and if you have a `src` folder try `{root}/src/middleware.js`.

Comment: To be more precise, the middleware file has to be on the same level as the `pages` folder, which is not necessarily on the root if you're using a `src` folder. See https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/middleware#using-middleware.

Comment: We have monorepo, middleware is working in one project but not in other. I don't see any reason why it won't.

Comment: @juliomalves I edited the answer to include your correct comment

Comment: Adding to this.. Im on next version 12.1.4.  I had to name my middleware.js file with a leading underscore.  Im not sure why that is, and I did not see that in their docs at all

Comment: @master_dodo can you explain more please? I use monorepo also (NX) and for now doesn't have that problem.

Answer (score 34):

For next **13.0.2 / 13.0.1**
if you are using **appDir: true** ( experimental )

if you want to hit middleware:

1. put middleware.ts in root project:
   ( as the same hierarchy as "app" folder, not inside app folder... )
2. make sure tsconfig has include: [..., "middleware.ts"]
3. make empty "pages" folder. ( based on [issue](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/43141) )
4. will hit every request:

```html
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'
import type { NextRequest } from 'next/server'

export function middleware(request: NextRequest ) {
    console.log('lol!!!')
}

export const config = {
  matcher: '/',
}
```

Comment: Wow. Why is this not in the docs?

Comment: @MichaelAngelo It's not in the documents because I believe the issue he linked is a bug. He's exploiting that bug to get the middleware to fire as he wants, not "as Next intends" so it could possibly be patched in the future which would make this answer stale.

Comment: I'm using next.js 13.4.19 and still had to move middleware.ts one level up (from app to root folder) in order to have it working.

Comment: Feb '24 and this is the answer if you use app router

Answer (score 18):

In my case it was not being called because I am using `pageExtensions` like this in the `next.config.js` file.

```
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  pageExtensions: ["page.tsx", "api.ts"],
};
```

So, in my case, the middleware should be called, either `middleware.page.ts` or `middleware.api.ts`. It took me a while to figure it out.

Comment: thx dude！If without your anwser, i would really took long time to solve it

Comment: heres the reference https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/next-config-js/pageExtensions

Comment: Thank you so much, this is crazy to find out for an older project. Amazing!

Answer (score 12):

https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/38546#discussioncomment-3127906

This ended up being my solution. I was using next 13.1. If you use a src folder than you need to have the middleware live in the `{root}/src/middleware.ts`

Comment: This is the correct answer. I have /src/app in my project, and placing the file in the src folder worked.

Answer (score 5):

if your pages and middleware are not on the same level, then it won't work.
here is an example of middleware working with Cookies.

```
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export default function middleware(req){
    let verify = req.cookies.get("loggedin");
    let url = req.url

    if(!verify && url.includes('/dashboard')){
        return NextResponse.redirect("http://localhost:3000/");
    }

    if (verify && url === "http://localhost:3000/") {
      return NextResponse.redirect("http://localhost:3000/dashboard");
    }


}
```

Answer (score 5):

Everything is simple (Next.js 13 app_dir):

- Check path: `src/middleware.ts`
- **Attention**, if you use TS extension for middleware, don't forgot about **TS** extension.
- `pageExtensions: ['ts', 'tsx']` (next.config.js)

Done.

Comment: This one is true. worked on Next 13.4.

Answer (score 4):

I have Next v14 with src/ directory.
The solution I've found, despite what documentation says, was moving middleware.ts from {root}/src to {root}

Comment: it worked for me within `src/` directory. but then again, i have `src/app/` where it didn't work.

Comment: Same here, works in `/` but not in `/src/`, odd.

Answer (score 3):

In case you're using NextJS version lower than 12.2.2, you will need to:

- Name your file with `_middleware.ts` or `_middlware.js`
- Place it **inside** `pages` directory

https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/middleware-upgrade-guide

Answer (score 3):

As of Next 13.4.7, if you are using the App Router, there is a bug that the middleware.ts/middleware.js file should sometimes be in the root directory instead of the app directory as stated in the docs.

Comment: This one did the trick for me. v14.0.1

Comment: i'm on next v14.1.0 & this worked for me.

Comment: Yeah, it's very weird but it also worked for me only in the root directory instead of the app directory. I am on v14.0.0

Answer (score 1):

I'm on next.js v14.1.0 & here's what worked for me.

I have a `src/app/` folder which contained `middleware.ts` but that didn't work.

So I moved it one level up in `src/` & that worked.

You can confirm with the following `middleware.ts` code:

```js
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server"

export default async function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
    console.log(request.method)
    console.log('inside the middleware')
}

export const config = {
    matcher: ["/api/login"],
}
```

where `src/app/api/login/route.ts` is a login route.

Now go request `/api/login` from login ui or code. Here's one way with code:

#### ./src/app/rate-limit/login.ts

```js
const LOCALHOST_URL = "http://localhost:3000"

async function main() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        const url = `${LOCALHOST_URL}/api/login`
        const email = `test${i}@example.com`
        const body = JSON.stringify({ email })

        const response = await fetch(url, { method: "POST", body })
        const data = await response.json()

        console.log({ data })
    }
}

main()
```

Now run `tsx ./src/app/rate-limit/login.ts` in another terminal to check the log on the server terminal.

Answer (score 0):

```
export const config = {
  // Matcher ignoring `/_next/` and `/api/`
  matcher: ['/((?!api|_next/static|_next/image|favicon.ico).*)']
}
```

i have this config save in middleware so I change `matcher: '/'` and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Next version: `"next": "14.0.1",`
Route: `app/api`

If you want to trigger the middleware, you need to specify the path matcher in the config,

```
// middleware.js

export const config = {
  matcher: ['/', '/api/:path/alpha', `/api/:path/beta`],
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue. I first moved middleware.ts within my `src` folder. This doesn't seem to work for me at least when its in the app level.

Also

I changed this

```
const nextConfig = {
  output: 'export',
  distDir: './dist', // Changes the build output directory to `./dist/`.
  publicRuntimeConfig: {
    // Will be available on both server and client
    backendUrl: "http://localhost:5001"
  },
}
```

To this (removed the output: export)

```
const nextConfig = {
  distDir: './dist', // Changes the build output directory to `./dist/`.
  publicRuntimeConfig: {
    // Will be available on both server and client
    backendUrl: "http://localhost:5001"
  },
}
```

Hopefully this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

you export default your middleware file

```js
export default async function middleWare(request: NextRequest) {
  const { pathname } = request.nextUrl;

  if (pathname === "/login" || pathname === "/admin") {
    return NextResponse.next();
  }
  const token = await getToken({ req: request });

  /* protected route for user */
  const userProctedRoutes = ["/"];
  /* protected route for admin */
  const adminProctedRoutes = ["/admin/dashboard"];

  if (
    token == null &&
    (userProctedRoutes.includes(pathname) ||
      adminProctedRoutes.includes(pathname))
  ) {
    return NextResponse.redirect(
      new URL("/login?error=Please login first", request.url)
    );
  }

  /* get user token */
  const user: CustomUser | null = token?.user as CustomUser;

  /* if user try to access admin routes */
  if (adminProctedRoutes.includes(pathname) && user.role == "User") {
    return NextResponse.redirect(
      new URL("/admin?error=please login first", request.url)
    );
  }
  /* if admin try to access user routes */
  if (userProctedRoutes.includes(pathname) && user.role == "Admin") {
    return NextResponse.redirect(
      new URL("/login?error=please login first", request.url)
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i was using nexjs version 12.0.8. it helped me only after upgrading to nextjs 14 (latest).

for checking next version

```
npm list next
```

for upgrading

```
npm install next@latest react@latest react-dom@latest eslint-config-next@latest
```

Answer (score -1):

Just to chime in, my mistake was that I called my file "middelware.ts" instead of "middleware.ts", mistakenly swopping the "l" and "e"...